# My monitor doesn't sleep if my mac is connected via HDMI: who's at fault?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, display, hdmi, dvi

I have a `MacBook5,1` running 10.8, and an `Asus VW246` monitor.

I connected it to the monitor using a "MiniDisplayPort->DVI(f) adapter" + a "DVI(m)-DVI(m) cable". Now I've bought a single "MiniDisplayPort-HDMI cable", and while it works, now when the Mac goes to sleep, the monitor stays awake in a "HDMI no signal" state.

Can I understand who's at fault: the Mac, the cable or the monitor?

- If it's the Mac, can this be worked-around somehow?
- If it's the cable, how can I make sure this won't happen with other cables?
- If it's the monitor I don't think there is anything to fix that, barring using DVI again.

Side-notes:

- the only reason I switched to HDMI is that I wanted a single cable, no converters, and I found a cheap HDMI one
- the cable namely supports audio too, but apparently this isn't working with this monitor – I haven't tested it with other monitors, thought (I'm not sure if this can help, I'm writing it "just in case")
- the "HDMI no signal" state is the same as when there's no cable attached

Comment: what does the monitor display without the cable ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 the exact same thing "HDMI no signal"

Comment: Than you have your answer. Mac does not sends the black out signal, it just disconnects.

Comment: @Buscar웃 you know of no workaround to that, or you _know_ there isn't one? (slight difference) Post it as an aswer anyway!

Comment: I do not know, but some monitors have the feature not to use the Hot connection, thus not actively seek signal as soon they detect the hdmi cable. Try if your monitor has that setting.